# Let $G$ be a group, $g\in G$. Let $\varphi_g:G\to G$ s.t. $\varphi_g(x)=gx$ for $x\in G$. For which $g\in G$ is $\varphi_g$ a homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ be a group, and let $g \in G$. Let $\varphi_g : G \to G $ be defined by $\varphi_g(x) = gx$ for $x \in G$. For which $g \in G$ is $\varphi_g$ a homomorphism?

I solved this below

Let $x , y \in G$
$$\varphi(xy) = g (xy) $$
in order to be homomorphism.
$$\varphi(xy) = \varphi (x) \varphi(y) $$
so $$g (xy) = gx gy$$
This is possible only if $g = e_G$ where $e_G$ is identity in $G$. Then
$$e_G (xy) = e_G(x) e_G(y)$$
$$(xy) = (x) (y)$$
$$\varphi(xy) = \varphi (x) \varphi(y) $$
Is this a correct reasoning?

Comment: That works, but it is easier. For all group homomorphisms, $\phi(1)=1,$ so …

Comment: You also haven’t explicitly show $g=e_G$ is the only solution to $gxy=gxgy.$ It is true, but that step can be made clearer.

Comment: How can I show the uniqueness. Any hint?

Comment: All the elements in $G$ are inversible therefore $gxy=gxgy\Rightarrow gx=gxg\Rightarrow x=xg\Rightarrow e_G=g$.

Comment: What uniqueness?

Comment: Yes, that's absolutely correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is good work. Well done! It needs some extra justification, though, as described by @ThomasAndrews in the comments above.

There's a quicker way.

**Lemma:** The only idempotent of a group is the identity.

*Proof:* Let $x^2=x$. Then $xx=x=ex$, so, multiplying on the right by $x^{-1}$, we get $x=e$.$\square$

We have

$$\begin{align}
g&=ge\\
&=\varphi_g(e)\\
&=\varphi_g(ee)\\
&=\varphi_g(e)\varphi_g(e)\\
&=gege\\
&=g^2.
\end{align}$$

Thus $g=e$.